# Android searchView with voice icon

Tags: android, user-interface

In an android app, I want to implement a searchView like this
[image]

There are some requirements:

1. the SearchIcon and the text("搜索")are in the middle of the searchView
2. a voiceIcon is inside the right side of the searchview.

3.the searchView is expanded by default.

I try to use the android searchView component, but i can't move the searchIcon to the middle of the searchView and I dont konw how to add an voiceIcon.

How can I do this,Thanks.

Comment: use the searchView component,but it can not move the sarchIcon and add a voiceIcon

Answer (score 2):

If you chose to follow the use of a SearchView, you will come accross the creation of a searchable item in XML.

To get the microphone logo, you can add this line to your searchable

```
android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
```

This will enable the voice module, and also add the microphone icon to your searchView if you follow the Android tutorial you can find here 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Answer (score 0):

I know that I shuold use custom layout to do this, so I write like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/orange_yellow"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp">
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/homeSearchView"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="5"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/voiceSearchIconImageView"
                            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/voiceSearchIconImageView">

                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                                android:id="@+id/searchIconImageView" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/search"
                                android:id="@+id/textView" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_voice"
                            android:id="@+id/voiceSearchIconImageView"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_action_scan"
                        android:id="@+id/scanImageButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and it seems work

[image]

the next step is to implement the search logic like SearchView component.

Answer (score 0):

you can also replace the mic icon with your custom icon
 by adding this to ur search_view in xml

`app:voiceIcon="@drawable/ic_mic`